# How to provide Username and Password on Postman while calling an API

Tags: postman

I tried to call an API from Postman and I give Username and password in authorisation tab in Postman and not working.

But I can access API data in the browser when I put the URL after successfully login with username and password as shown:

[image]

So how can I give my credentials to postman to get API data?

Comment: Is this a POST request? Have you tried adding those details to the request body in a form rather than in the Auth section.

Comment: No.This is a GET request

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to see what parameters it sends when requested via browser?

You can do that in Chrome:

1. Developer tools (Ctrl + Shift + I)
2. Network tab
3. XHR

Then send your request. 
You'll be able to see request headers and body.
Then you can copy the parameters over to your postman call. 
Most calls like that are using authorization token. You'll also be able to see if the token was requested in the separate call and if it was passed as a parameter.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueBiF.png)